# python handling output of different threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I am using python multi threading to start a host of threads which executes a set of commands and prints result to stdout. Now i want to have a designated file for each thread having the the prints.

I have seen numerous questions on this site but solutions still looks far.

I stumbled upon multiprocessing to be a very good approach for this , but i am getting the below error which is a know bug in python 2.7.x

*AssertionError    : assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name*

With the framework i am using being based on python 2.7.x i cannot update the python version to 3 or beyond as multiprocessing is working fine there.

Is there any approach where each threads output can be captured in a separate file? Thanks!!!!

Comment: Have you tried using Python 2.7.11? This issue was fixed in that version (or should have been).

Comment: yes i have been using 2.7.12 , but the issue persists.

Comment: is there any way i can include the fix in my python 2.7.12?